# how to get append table data and getting clicked table row data using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append some table row data using ajax and getting that data via jquery
but the thing is both functions are working.

this code function well

```
function podetails(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../phpfile/getpurchaseordetails.php?pid=" + pid,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                event_data += '<tr id="'+ value.poid + '">';
                event_data += '<td id="co">' + value.countt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td id="po">' + value.podetail + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td id="sa">' + value.saless + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td id="pr">' + value.productt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td id="qt">' + value.qty + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td id="da">' + value.date + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td><button class="btn btn-dark editt" onclick="dog()" type="submit" name="insert" id=" '+ value.poid + '">Edit</button></td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#list_table_json > tbody").empty();
            $("#list_table_json").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function (d) {
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
        }
    });
}
```

in this code also function well but alert shows nothing(empty)

```
function dog() {

    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find('#co').text();
    alert($text);

    var podetail = $('#list_table_json').closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var pocode = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var saleline = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var product = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var qty = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text();
    alert(podetail);}
```

how do I get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this update to my code

```
    function podetails(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../phpfile/getpurchaseordetails.php?pid=" + pid,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(data);
            // console.log(data);
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                event_data += '<tr class="' + value.poid + '">';
                event_data += '<td class="co">' + value.countt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="po">' + value.podetail + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="sa">' + value.saless + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="pr">' + value.productt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="qt">' + value.qty + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="da">' + value.date + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td><button class="btn btn-dark editt" onclick="dog(' + value.poid + ')" type="submit" name="insert" id=" ' + value.poid + '">Edit</button></td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#list_table_json > tbody").empty();
            $("#list_table_json").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function (d) {
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
        }
    });
}

function dog($dag) {

    var podetail = $('.'+$dag).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var pocode = $('.'+$dag).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var saleline = $('.'+$dag).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var product = $('.'+$dag).find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var qty = $('.'+$dag).find('td:eq(4)').text();
    alert(podetail);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear to me but maybe try this :

```
function podetails(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../phpfile/getpurchaseordetails.php?pid=" + pid,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);
            var event_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                console.log(value);
                event_data += '<tr class="'+ value.poid + '">';
                event_data += '<td class="co">' + value.countt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="po">' + value.podetail + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="sa">' + value.saless + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="pr">' + value.productt + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="qt">' + value.qty + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td class="da">' + value.date + '</td>';
                event_data += '<td><button class="btn btn-dark editt" onclick="dog()" type="submit" name="insert" id=" '+ value.poid + '">Edit</button></td>';
                event_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#list_table_json > tbody").empty();
            $("#list_table_json").append(event_data);
        },
        error: function (d) {
            /*console.log("error");*/
            alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
        }
    });
}

function dog() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var $text = $row.find('.co').text();
    alert($text);

    var podetail = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();;
    var pocode = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var saleline = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var product = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var qty = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text();
    alert(podetail);
}
```

I replaced "id" by "class" since there can only one element with a specific id per page. There's a chance that the first element with the "co" id is empty, this is the reason why you only get empty values when searching by id.

Comment: I guess it means that both alerts are empty. Is it normal that you use "value.countt" ? Maybe it is "value.count" with a single "t" ?

Comment: nope, that function work properly I got all data, the issue is that "dog" function. I think this code has the issue " var podetail = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();"

Comment: Well you could try with "var podetail = $(this).closest("tr").find('.po').text();" but since it doesn't work few lines before I bet it won't work either.

Comment: check below code, I make some upgrade to my code. there is an issue with this part $(this).closest("tr")